# SessionAuthentication vs OAuth2Authentication to work with Django and Angularjs

Tags: django, rest, angularjs

i'm currently learning about [django-rest](http://django-rest-framework.org/) and i'd like to interact with an Angularjs application.
The main idea is to build an API with django-rest serving on localhost:8000 and call it with a nodejs/angularjs serving on localhost:9000
the main question is: how to authenticate an user through angularjs ?
The [documentation](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication) says

> Session authentication is appropriate for AJAX clients that are
>   running in the same session context as your website.

because django and angularjs are not in the same context, does it means i have to use oauth2 to play with authentication ?

Thanks for your lights :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it means i have to use oauth2 to play with authentication?

Of course not. You can use [`TokenAuthentication`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) or even [`BasicAuthentication`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#basicauthentication).

I myself most of the times use something similar to `TokenAuthentication` but handmade. The only concern here is passing token in requests.

**EDIT:**

If you perchance not satisfied with options provided by Django REST you can write your own middleware to handle authentication. The idea here is to [authenticate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) user. Pass to him some token and then check for that token in your custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/middleware/).

Comment: thanks for your help. It's to me a little difficult to understand what are pros and cons with each solution. I had the idea that a mobile app for example will use TokenAuthentication and AJAX app will use SessionAuthentication but in fact not :( Beacause i'll have an agent which will call my API, i'll maybe use TokenAuthentication because only one authentication sheme will be easier to maintain :) Agree ?

Comment: Absolutely. If your clients (no matter mobile or desktop) have different context with your API or even may have different context and totaly decoupled from it stick with `TokenAuthentication`.

Comment: great i'm in a good way :) i just re-read the django-rest doc and it says " OAuth2 is more simple to work with than OAuth1, and provides much better security than simple token authentication." Then if TokenAuthentication is a good solution to bind desktop, mobile apps, and if Oauth2 is more secure, then i'll finally use oauth2. Thanks for your help, it helped me so much !!